# Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.selectBook is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

im a newbie for reactjs and was following a react basic course on udemy.
I get the following error on my console log. Can anybody assist with me?.

```
bundle.js:21818 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.selectBook is not a function
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**containers/book-list.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectBook } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class BookList extends Component {
    renderList() {
        return this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
                <li 
                    key={book.title} 
                    onClick={() => this.props.selectBook(book)} 
                    className="list-group-item">
                    {book.title}
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        books: state.books
    };
}

//Anythin returned from this function will end up as props
// on the BookList container
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    // whenever selectBook is called, the result should be passed
    // to all of our reducers
    return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook }, dispatch);
}

// Promote BookList from a component to a container - it needs to know 
// about this new dispatch method, selectBook. Make it available
// as a prop.
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export function selectBook(book) {
    console.log('A book has been selected:', book.title);
}
```

**components/app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import BookList from '../containers/book-list';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BookList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide whole code.

Comment: how can i show multiple files? @kinduser

Comment: Post the file where you are using `selectBook` variable.

Comment: added in the question description @kinduser thanks for quick prompt.

Comment: Why did you place `selectBook` function inside `actions` folder? It's misleading. Actions are - let's say - reserved for redux. Anyways - try to move that function into `book-list` file and see if the error persists.

Comment: yes. i think its for tutorial demonstration purpose. anyway. i added the function to book-list.js file. but no luck.

Comment: Post your modified file and error which appears (if it's different than before).

Comment: here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/x6ugon6j/

Comment: But now error is different. `Book-list` module cannot be found. Make sure you import it properly.

Comment: seems like it also linked properly. *see the file at end of question description

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

```
// didnt have included the mapDispatchToProps function call in below lines.
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

Comment: this is what did it for me, I am following Stephen Grider's udemy course

Answer (score 5):

Use `import selectBook from '../actions/index'` instead of `import { selectBook } from '../actions/index';`

Answer (score 1):

For someone who already included the `mapDispatchToProps` function call, i.e. `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);`

Look through actions/index.js and see if you're using default export or not.
If not you would require `{}` around while importing selectBook.

```
if (using default export) { 

    import selectBook from '../actions/index';
}
else {

    import { selectBook } from '../actions/index';
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to export selectBook action so that it's available inside the application

```
export function selectBook() {...}
```