# _this2.props.signup is not a function in React Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Please note** that I've already checked answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133591/uncaught-typeerror-this2-props-selectbook-is-not-a-function) question and nothing seems to work.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/rwieruch/react-redux-firebase-authentication) repo as a boilerplate. Instead of firebase database, I'm trying to send username and email with the firebase auth userid , to the node server. I created an action creator `signup` to handle this.

This is `signup.js` action creator

```
import * as types from '../constants/action_types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const signup = (user) => {
    console.log(user);
    return async dispatch => {
       try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/user/register', user)
        const data = await {response};
        dispatch({
            type : types.SIGN_UP,
            payload : data.fromback
        })
       } catch (error) {
           console.lot(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've connected it with the component with `mapDispatchToProps`., So,under the `SignUpPage` component, React dev tools shows `signup` as a function. But when it get triggers, it gives an error saying `_this2.props.signup is not a function` Why's that ?

This is my `SignUpPage` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Link,
  withRouter,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { auth } from '../../firebase';
import * as routes from '../../constants/routes';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {signup} from './../../actions/signup';

const SignUpPage = ({ history }) =>
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
    <SignUpForm history={history} />
  </div>

const updateByPropertyName = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
  [propertyName]: value,
});

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  username: '',
  email: '',
  passwordOne: '',
  passwordTwo: '',
  error: null,
};

class SignUpForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    const {
      username,
      email,
      passwordOne,
    } = this.state;

    const {
      history,
    } = this.props;

    auth.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
      .then(authUser => {
        const userid = authUser.user.uid;
        const user = { email, userid };
        this.props.signup(user);

      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState(updateByPropertyName('error', error));
      });

    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      username,
      email,
      passwordOne,
      passwordTwo,
      error,
    } = this.state;

    const isInvalid =
      passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
      passwordOne === '' ||
      username === '' ||
      email === '';

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          value={username}
          onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('username', event.target.value))}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Full Name"
        />
        <input
          value={email}
          onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('email', event.target.value))}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email Address"
        />
        <input
          value={passwordOne}
          onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('passwordOne', event.target.value))}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <input
          value={passwordTwo}
          onChange={event => this.setState(updateByPropertyName('passwordTwo', event.target.value))}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
        />
        <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>

        { error && <p>{error.message}</p> }
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const SignUpLink = () =>
  <p>
    Don't have an account?
    {' '}
    <Link to={routes.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link>
  </p>

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ signup }, dispatch)

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(SignUpPage));

export {
  SignUpForm,
  SignUpLink,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a prop,
you've imported it as a function,
you can directly use it as function like this

```
import {signup} from './../../actions/signup';
.....
auth.doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
  .then(authUser => {
    const userid = authUser.user.uid;
    const user = { email, userid };
    signup(user);

  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState(updateByPropertyName('error', error));
  });
```

Comment: This works. However I was trying to pass it as a props. I posted the same on a [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8zi4og/action_doesnt_get_called_and_no_errors_either/) got the answer I was looking for.

Btw, why would we need to pass actions as props if we can directly access them like you mentioned ?